# Hide saved cards and newsletter subscriptions from Customer Account sidebar

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.4.3

I was led to believe that if the following code was added into 'Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml', this would remove them options but they still remain visible even after doing the relevent commands afterwards. I have also tried to inseet them into 'Magento_Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml' to no avail either. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I am trying to remove these options 
[image: Image of what I am trying to remove]

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <!-- Subscription link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>


    <!-- My credit card link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>


</body>
```

Comment: have you cleaned your cache?

Comment: Code is fine, you have actually placed it in `/path/to/webroot/app/design/Vendor/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Then run the following command from the CLI :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```